.NET 8 Client/Server App - Client Program.cs is not executing
First off, I don't have the reputation to post comments or "like" an existing post: Client program.cs is never executed when creating Blazor WebAssembly apps in .net 8
However, I am experiencing this same issue and my server program.cs contains this code:
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Lexican.Client._Imports).Assembly);

The server project handles all the login & identity processing and then redirects back to the client where I use services to get the data needed.
As soon as I login & redirect back to the client, none of the injected services are available because the client program.cs did not execute.
My client program.cs is NOT executing at all... I added a breakpoint and even on an anonymous session, it is not fire.
Here is the code:
global using MudBlazor.Services;
global using MudBlazor;
global using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAdminService, AdminService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWordService, WordService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IStudentTestService, StudentTestService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEventMessages, EventMessages>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorageAsSingleton();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICommonMethods, CommonMethods>(); 

builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage(); 
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddMudServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Create a logger
var logger = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

// Log service registrations
builder.Services.LogServiceRegistrations(logger);

await app.RunAsync();


This is quite likely a configuration issue, but I can't find it.
What can I check or change next? What else do you need to see before you can offer help?

Console.WriteLines added to show that the client program.cs is not executed...

and...


Most probably your Program.cs starts your entire app, so if you are seeing app, it must have executed :) More generally, if you want to know if something executed (in code you've written), set the breakpoint and see if it is being hit, when you expect it to.

You didn't state why the answer on that other question didn't help you: turn off prerendering or register in both projects.

You ask a question about injecting services but do not show a single detail. Ask based on a [mre] .

@MichałTurczyn well, that is a good point.. you'd think it executed. I guess it is also important to mention that the client/program.cs executes for anonymous access, but after I login, I get the same error as noted in the linked post. .. If I checked the "Remember Me" when logging in, when I restart the app then it errors immediately, it does not hit my breakpoint in the client/program.cs

@HenkHolterman My apologies, but I didn't see anything flagged as the answer that corrected the previous question. I saw the original poster mention that he did not want to disable prerender and  it was also stated "This has fixed the problem by forcing the program.cs to run immediately" .. I do not know how to force the client/program.cs to run.

The breakpoints in program.cs may not be getting hit because of the startup process. From the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-8.0&preserve-view=true&tabs=visual-studio Breakpoints are not hit during app startup before the debug proxy is running. This includes breakpoints in the Program file and breakpoints in the OnInitialized{Async} lifecycle methods of components that are loaded by the first page requested from the app.. You may have to use Console WriteLine to get info out as inconvenient as that is

Could you check you have added all the WebAssembly scripts in your project. Check middleware and routing configurations. verify that PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider is correctly implemented and integrates well with authentication flows.it would be great if you can share the reproducible sample and try to use the debugging to get more detail about the issue and check the flow

@JalpaPanchal I can try ... but this is a large project that I upgraded from .Net 7 to 8... I have not tried to recreate the issue yet with a new project. However, this is in my client program.cs but as I have stated, it is not executed... builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>(); 

@EJDev ... I add writelines to both client & server... only the server is hit. (I'll add the screenshots above)

@Brian is it possible for you to reproduce the issue in new project?

@JalpaPanchal ... sorry for the latent response. I am working on this as a side project. So, I am rebuilding it in a new .Net 8 WASM and just adding the basic nav & layouts that I need... I am getting this compiler error .. LoggedIn.OnInitializedAsync(): no suitable method found to override . This doesn't make sense to me as that same override is used in all my razor components that need a code-behind file. I'm struggling here.

It seems I need to add : ComponentBase the partial class definition in .Net 8 #shruggle .. still learning.

@Brian The error you mentioned in comment you are getting which indicates the base method is not available in the context where you're trying to override it. make sure that the component class correctly inherits from ComponentBase or any other appropriate Blazor component base class. try this code:  public partial class LoggedIn : ComponentBase      {          protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()          {          }      }

Regarding your error in the image, you have shared, it says missing service registration, which might be the reason for application to fail during the dependency injection process. This can explain why the client-side initialization is not working correctly after the login process.make sure service mentioned in the exception message is correctly registered.
